# Does OpenERP SAAS support use of related field?

Tags: odoo, saas

I am using `OpenERP 7.0 SAAS environment`.

I have to use details of `partner_id` from `res.partner` in custom table. Is there any method to access the values of selected partner_id to be used in that table.

Thanks & Regards,
Atchuthan

Answer (score 1):

No, because on the SaaS/Cloud environment you can only create custom fields via the user interface, and the UI does not currently support creating function fields (`fields.related` is a kind of function field).

Depending on your use case there's a good chance you can find an alternative satisfying approach, though ;-)

Comment: is there any other method other than the use of **RELATED field**

Comment: Not if you want to do exactly what a related field does. But as I said it really depends on your use case, you might want to explain it. (BTW I'm just repeating what I said in the answer... ;-))

Comment: `i want the phone number of res.partner in x_test with field x_phone.. `


How to deal with this situation??

Atleast provide me details of what u described as **"Not if you want to do exactly what a related field does"**